# How to evaluate a string expression and return the value in C?

Tags: c, string, expression, evaluation

I am trying to evaluate an expression taken as a character array and return the result of the expression.

eg:

```
char *myeExpression []= "(1+2) * 3"
```

should return result 9.

Here is my code:

```
struct node {
double element;
struct node *next;
} *head;

void push(int c);      // function to push a node onto the stack
int pop();             // function to pop the top node of stack
void traceStack();      // function to //print the stack values

 int prece(char j)
{
if(j=='*'||j=='/')
{
   j=3;
}
else
{
    if(j=='+'||j=='-')
    {
       j=2;
    }
    else
    {
       j=1;
    }
}
return j;
}


 int evaluate(char *  a) {
int i = 0, j = 0,k,l,a1,b1;   // indexes to keep track of current position
char *exp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
double res = 0;

char stack[5];
char tmp;
head = NULL;

//  converting an infix to a postfix

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    a1=prece(a[i]);
    b1=prece(stack[k]);
    if(a1<=b1)
    {
        exp[l]=a[i];
        l++;
    }
    else
    {
        stack[k]=a[i];
        k++;

    }
}
for(i=k;i>0;i--)
{
    exp[l]=stack[i];
    l++;
}



//end
i=0;
j=0;
k=0;


while( (tmp=exp[i++]) != '\0') {    // repeat till the last null terminator
    // if the char is operand, pust it into the stack
    if(tmp >= '0' && tmp <= '9') {
        int no = tmp - '0';
        push(no);
        continue;
    }

    if(tmp == '+') {
        int no1 = pop();
        int no2 = pop();
        push(no1 + no2);
    } else if (tmp == '-') {
        int no1 = pop();
        int no2 = pop();
        push(no1 - no2);
    } else if (tmp == '*') {
        int no1 = pop();
        int no2 = pop();
        push(no1 * no2);
    } else if (tmp == '/') {
        int no1 = pop();
        int no2 = pop();
        push(no1 / no2);
    }
}
return pop();

}

void push(int c) {
if(head == NULL) {
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->element = c;
    head->next = NULL;
} else {
    struct node *tNode;
    tNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tNode->element = c;
    tNode->next = head;
    head = tNode;
}
}

 int pop() {
struct node *tNode;
tNode = head;
head = head->next;
return tNode->element;
}
```

Infix Expression evaluation happens but not completely. 
Getting wrong result ie 3 in stead of 9.

Comment: If this is your complete code, and you are "lost", then you need to first think about what you are trying to do, think about the algorithm, and the steps and then move forward. You still have quite a bit to do.

Comment: Soory, had posted the wrong code.. please check now.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Your stack stores `double` in the `struct node`; you pop values off the stack into `int`.  This seems an odd arrangement.  For debugging, either step through the code with a debugger or add enough print statements that you can see what is happening.

Comment: It might be a good exercise to do a reverse polish implementation first.  (eg, parse `1 2+3*`).  That is much easier to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't explicitly ignore or otherwise handle blanks; this is one cause of trouble? The compiler indicates that:

- `k` is not initialized
- `l` is not initialized

These uninitialized values are used as indexes into arrays.  You use `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` to scan the string, regardless of its actual length.  This is not a recipe for happiness.

Parentheses are given precedence 1 (low); usually, they're given a high precedence.  You need to decide how they're handled as you're converting from infix to prefix.

You compare things with the precedence of `stack[k]` before you've pushed anything onto the stack.  In general, your infix to prefix conversion seems unreliable.  You should concentrate on getting that correct before going further.

You must learn either to run your code in a debugger, stepping through it line by line to see what's going wrong, or to add debugging print statements (that's the way I normally work).

Answer (score 0):

You could learn lex and yacc as they take much of the difficulty out of building lexers and parsers. "calc" is a standard example which can calculate simple arithmetic expressions. You can find it, for example, [here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs2121/ho/node4.html).